# best practice for communicating between two beans that back the same page

Tags: jsf

We are making the transition to bootstrap pages. As part of this, we are making most of our dialogs into simple include files that get rendered on demand. The include files have their own backing bean to minimize code duplication.

The typical use case is when a user enters a page a datatable shows a list of things. The user selects one or more rows in the table and then clicks a button to perform an action. The page is re-rendered using ajax. The datatable is not displayed but the former dialog is. The user then does whatever bulk operation the former dialog does and clicks execute (or cancel). The page is then re-rendered with the datatable showing and the former dialog box not.

The problem here is simple; how do you set the render flags on the datatable and former dialog box? Each of the beans needs to set the render flag of the other bean. I blithely tried injecting each bean into the other and promptly got a circular injection error at runtime. I've gone to having a callback interface that the datatable beans implement. When the former dialog bean gets injected, the datatable bean sets itself up to be called back. This works but I am not sure it's the best way to do it. Being an old swing programmer, I considered using property change listeners, which are much more robust than the simple interface, but I'm not sure what the implications of using them in a managed bean environment are. I did check out the messaging API but it clearly doesn't apply to this case.

So, what's the best way for two view beans that are backing the same page to talk to each other?